# DropDownList inside ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, linqdatasource

I have a DropDownList inside a ListView. The ListView shows employees of a company, and the DDL lists groups to which they can be assigned.

I used 2 separate datasources. One to list the employees, and one to list the groups. It looks fine, but whenever I try to update the groups, it doesn't register.

### How do I make sure that the DDL is a part of the update query for employees, even though it's connected to another datasource?

I haven't been able to find anything about this on here. Appreciate your time, thanks. :)

DataSources:

```
                <asp:LinqDataSource 
                    ID="LinqDataSource_Employees" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ContextTypeName="Blabla.bla.myContext" 
                    EntityTypeName="" 
                    OrderBy="Group_ID, DisplayName" 
                    TableName="Employees" 
                    EnableDelete="True" 
                    EnableInsert="True" 
                    EnableUpdate="True">
                </asp:LinqDataSource>

                <asp:LinqDataSource 
                    ID="LinqDataSource_Groups" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ContextTypeName="Blabla.bla.myContext" 
                    EntityTypeName="" 
                    Select="new (ID, Name)" 
                    TableName="Groups">
                </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

EditItemTemplate:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="">
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="ID_UserNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID_UserName") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="DisplayNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DisplayName") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="EmailAddressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmailAddress") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneNumberTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PhoneNumber") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="GroupDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource_Groups" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more [digging](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-asp-net-4-c-vb/90711-dropdownlist-several-hard-coded-values-inside-formview.html), I found a clue on how to continue.

Turns out, that if you use Bind on the Property **SelectedValue**, it'll bind to the DataSource of the ListView, and not the one that was declaratively set in the DataSource property. :)

```
<asp:DropDownList 
 ID="GroupDropDownList" 
 runat="server" 
 DataSourceID="LinqDataSource_Groups" 
 DataTextField="Name" 
 DataValueField="ID" 
 SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Group_ID") %>' />
```

Hope this helps someone. :)